# Spring Security in Grails runnable jar redirects to HTTP

Tags: spring, http, security, grails

I'm using a grails 3 runnable jar with spring Security behind a reverse proxy handling https to http traffic (and https to http redirects), forwarding it to http://my-host:8080

For all my `/login/**` calls , grails is sending "302 redirect" to http

For example a `/login/authenticate` XHR is redirected with the header
`Location: http://my-big-ip/login/ajaxSuccess`, etc.

It's not using the `serverURL` parameter that I set in application.yml to `https://my-big-ip`

My jar is using embedded tomcat since I have this in my build.gradle

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
```

The logs I get about this redirect

```
2019-03-27 15:56:34,415 DEBUG http-nio-8088-exec-5  org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache - Removing DefaultSavedRequest from session if present  
2019-03-27 15:56:34,415 DEBUG http-nio-8088-exec-5  grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler - Redirecting to Ajax Success Url: /login/ajaxSuccess  
2019-03-27 15:56:34,415 DEBUG http-nio-8088-exec-5  grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.GrailsRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to '/login/ajaxSuccess'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you will need to add this to your application/runtime.(groovy|yml):

```
server."use-forward-headers" = true
```

There is a good bit of documentation (about this and other things) here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html that may be helpful if you are interested in additional details.

Comment: Thanks! I was completely unaware of this doc. Coupled with the fact that our IT changed the reverse proxy on me and the new one was not sending these headers..

Comment: Thanks a lot! Had exactly the same issue with Grails 3.3.9 running on OpenShift. Solved it by putting
```
server:
  use-forward-headers: true
```
into our application.yml